# Can a double pointer be written in two ways in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays, double-pointer

Do the following pieces of code do the exact same thing?

is `*(*(array+ x) + y) = 1;` the same as `array[x][y] = 1;`

Comment: Assuming `array` is a pointer to pointer, a pointer of arrays, or a 2D array, it is better to use array syntax if you intend to represent operations on elements on an array.   However, if you really want to make your code harder to read - for others or even for yourself in future - you can also mix the two, such as `*(array[x] + y) = 1` or `(*(array + x))[y] = 1` or even `y[*(array + x)] = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `array` is a double-pointer, array of pointers, or 2-D array type, yes.

If it's a user-defined type, then `operator[]` and `operator+` might be overridden in inconsistent ways.  For example, if `array` is a `std::vector` then `array[x]` will work and `*(array + x)` will not.